# How to amend this mysql query to show win percentage?

Tags: mysql

This query below:

```
SELECT member, count(*) Wins 
FROM (SELECT player2_name as member from results 
WHERE player1_id = 2 AND player1_result = 'W' AND community_id = 16 
UNION ALL SELECT player1_name FROM results WHERE player2_id = 2
AND player2_result = 'W' AND community_id = 16) AS T 
group by member ORDER BY Wins DESC
```

Produces a result such as:

```
+---------+-----------+
| member  |    Wins   |
+---------+-----------+
| Player 1|     4     |
| Player 2|     3     |
| Player 3|     3     |
+---------+-------------+
```

To make the data more useful (as each player may have played a different number of games) I want to show an extra column 'win percentage'.

-> This is based on the number of games each player has played / wins. - if outputting a % isn't possible directly in MySQL then a decimal would be fine i.e 0.76

How can I amend my existing query to produce an output as below:

`+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| member  |    Wins   | Games Played  |  Win %  |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| Player 1|     4     |       8       |    0.50 |
| Player 2|     3     |       3       |    1.00 |
| Player 3|     3     |       5       |    0.60 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+---------+`

I was hoping to just add in something along the lines of:

```
SELECT GamesPlayed FROM (SELECT player1_name as member from results 
WHERE player1_id = 2 AND community_id = 16 
UNION ALL SELECT player2_name FROM results WHERE player2_id = 2
AND community_id = 16) AS GP
```

and then on Line 1 :

```
 SELECT member, count(*) Wins, round(sum(wins/GamesPlayed(1),2) WinPercentage
```

But thats jut a very rough hopefull guess at how I see it working.

Latest test data:
[image]

Comment: Can you still alter your database schema? A table with two records per "game" (one per participant) would be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I could do but i'd prefer not to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

**Updated query**

```
SELECT 
    T.member
    , count(*) Wins 
    , total.gamesPlayed
    , count(*)/total.gamesPlayed as winPercentage
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            player2_name as member 
        from results 
        WHERE 
            player1_id = 2 
            AND player1_result = 'W' 
            AND community_id = 16 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 
            player1_name 
        FROM results 
            WHERE player2_id = 2
            AND player2_result = 'W' 
            AND community_id = 16
    ) AS T 
    ,   (
            select
                u.member
                , sum(u.gamesPlayed) as gamesPlayed
            from
                (
                    select
                        player2_name as member
                        , count(*) gamesPlayed
                    from results
                    where
                        player1_id = 2 
                        AND community_id = 16 
                    group  by player2_name
                    union
                    select
                        player1_name as member
                        , count(*) gamesPlayed
                    from results
                    where
                        player2_id = 2 
                        AND community_id = 16 
                    group  by player2_name
                ) as u /* union of two */
            group by member 
    ) as total
where
    T.member = total.member
group by T.member 
ORDER BY Wins DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Lee, it's just popped up an error on line 31..#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(*) gamesPlayed
                    from results
                    where
' at line 31

Comment: Sorry, I forgot two commas in Line 31 and 40 respectively (before `count(*)` in the subquery `u`).  Since I do not have your tables, I can't run the query so there may be other minor syntax errors, but hopefully my query can give you some idea how to find the total and you can take the query from there.

Comment: Almost there but it is giving the wrong data for the wrong player - i will upload a screenshot to explain.  

In the screen shot gamesPlayed against Sultan should be 4, and gamesPlayed against G should be 1...

Comment: In your original query, you have `player2_name` used with `player1_id`, and then `player1_name` used with `player2_id`.  I presume that is intentional, right? (That is, it is capturing the idea of an "opponent").  I am following the logic in my query above.

Comment: Ah I'll take a look - thanks for the help, should be able to sort out my mistakes from here